# What are the rules for resolving class-specific overloads of operator delete on polymorphic classes?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

[This cppreference.com page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) says that:

> The delete expression looks for appropriate deallocation function's
>   name firstly in the class scope, starting from the most derived type
>   if the class is polymorphic, and after that in the global scope. Note,
>   that as per name lookup rules, any deallocation functions declared in
>   class scope hides all global deallocation functions. When deleting a
>   polymorphic object, even though a different function may be executed
>   at run time, the statically visible version of operator delete must be
>   accessible in order to compile.

So I wrote a program to test this:

main.cpp:

```
#include "Factory.h"

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Base *b1 = getBase();
    delete b1;

    Base *b2 = getBaseArray(1);
    delete[] b2;
}
```

Factory.h:

```
#ifndef FACTORY_H_INCLUDED
#define FACTORY_H_INCLUDED

#include "Base.h"

Base* getBase();
Base* getBaseArray(std::size_t);

#endif // FACTORY_H_INCLUDED
```

Factory.cpp:

```
#include "Factory.h"
#include "Child.h"

Base* getBase()
{
    return new Child;
}

Base* getBaseArray(std::size_t s)
{
    return new Child[s];
}
```

Base.h:

```
#ifndef BASE_H_INCLUDED
#define BASE_H_INCLUDED

#include <cstddef>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    static void* operator new(std::size_t sz);
    static void* operator new[](std::size_t sz);
    static void operator delete(void *ptr, std::size_t sz);
    static void operator delete[](void *ptr, std::size_t sz);
};

#endif // BASE_H_INCLUDED
```

Base.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Base.h"

void* Base::operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "Base operator new called" << std::endl;
    return ::operator new(sz);
}
void* Base::operator new[](std::size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "Base operator new[] called" << std::endl;
    return ::operator new(sz);
}
void Base::operator delete(void *ptr, std::size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "Base operator delete called" << std::endl;
    ::operator delete(ptr);
}
void Base::operator delete[](void *ptr, std::size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "Base operator delete[] called" << std::endl;
    ::operator delete(ptr);
}
```

Child.h:

```
#ifndef CHILD_H_INCLUDED
#define CHILD_H_INCLUDED

#include "Base.h"

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Child() {}
    static void* operator new(std::size_t sz);
    static void* operator new[](std::size_t sz);
    static void operator delete(void *ptr, std::size_t sz);
    static void operator delete[](void *ptr, std::size_t sz);
};

#endif // CHILD_H_INCLUDED
```

Child.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Child.h"

void* Child::operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "Child operator new called" << std::endl;
    return ::operator new(sz);
}
void* Child::operator new[](std::size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "Child operator new[] called" << std::endl;
    return ::operator new(sz);
}
void Child::operator delete(void *ptr, std::size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "Child operator delete called" << std::endl;
    ::operator delete(ptr);
}
void Child::operator delete[](void *ptr, std::size_t sz)
{
    std::cout << "Child operator delete[] called" << std::endl;
    ::operator delete(ptr);
}
```

The result with GCC 4.9.1 appears to be consistent with cppreference.com's page for `delete` but not with `delete[]`:

```
Child operator new called
Child operator delete called
Child operator new[] called
Base operator delete[] called
```

Is this correct? I was expecting `delete[]` to have the same behavior.

Comment: The function `Base* getBaseArray(std::size_t s)` is dangerous IMHO: You cannot expect `Base*` to point to the first element of an array, since `sizeof(Base) == sizeof(Child)` is, in general, not guaranteed. Hence, you should not use a pointer to the first element in an array of `Child*` when a pointer to the first element in an array of `Base` is expected. This is probably also the underlying reason for the behaviour of `delete[]`.

Comment: [expr.delete]/3 "In the second alternative (delete
array) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined." Hence, `delete[] b2;` invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @dyp That makes sense, and I wouldn't ever really do that anyway. I was just trying to check my understanding of how delete overloads worked before I actually attempted using it in a project.

Comment: cppreference seems a bit imprecise here: The passage you quoted does not tell us *which* class is searched, and indeed that the polymorphism part only applies to the *delete object* form, not *delete array*.

Comment: @dyp OK, that's what I needed to know. I really should get a copy of the standard to keep on hand when I have questions like this.